# How can I insert '\' before each '/' in url?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have the variable URL_1 = `https://my/sample/url`. How do I can get URL_2 = `https:\/\/my\/sample\/url` ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to use the URL in a sed or perl or whatever regex (and the `/`s in the URL break the command), it's worth noting that sed and perl and many other programs allow you to use another character as the delimiter.  e.g. you can use `=` or `:` or a comma or whatever as the delimiter.  Use something that **isn't** going to be in the URL.   `:` and `/` are always going to be in a URL, so you can't use those.  `?` and `=` and `&` are also very common in GET urls.   A comma is not impossible, but fairly uncommon in a URl so it's a reasonable separator to try.

Comment: e.g. `sed -e "s,$URL,replacement,g"` will work unless $URL contains a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a shell like `bash`:

```bsh
URL_1='https://my/sample/url'
URL_2=${URL_1//\//\\\/}
```

This uses the `${variable//pattern/replacement}` substitution available in some shells, with `URL_1` as the variable, the string `\/`, i.e. an escaped slash, as the pattern, and `\\\/`, i.e. an escaped backslash followed by an escaped slash, as the replacement text.  The substitution replaces each match of the pattern with the replacement text, and the code above stores the result in the variable `URL_2`.

Testing:

```
$ URL_1='https://my/sample/url'
$ URL_2=${URL_1//\//\\\/}
$ printf '%s\n' "$URL_2"
https:\/\/my\/sample\/url
```

You could also use

```bsh
URL_2=${URL_1//'/'/'\/'}
```

(i.e., use single quotes instead of backslash escaping).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$  sed 's%/%\\/%g' < <(echo https://my.domain.com/blabla/temp.htm)
https:\/\/my.domain.com\/blabla\/temp.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this way-

```
user@node-01:~> echo https://my/sample/url > ./test1.txt
user@node-01:~> cat test1.txt 
https://my/sample/url
user@node-01:~> sed 's/\//\\\//g' test1.txt 
https:\/\/my\/sample\/url
```

If you want to replace inline please use sed **-i** 
Cheers!

Comment: And how is that different from my answeer ?

Comment: @Cbhihe your code is ideal for copy cat. My code is basically explains what's happening within each set. Cheers!